# How to render videos in a flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-video

I'm trying to render videos in a flatList, however I think the videos are reloaded when I scroll the FlatList. Could it be that the flatList interfere with react-native-video loading system?

Here is the video component

```js
const Video = (props) => {
    const { item, paused, index } = props;
    const videoRef = useRef(null);

    return (
        <Video
            ref={videoRef}
            style={styles.video}
            paused={paused}
            resizeMode="cover"
            source={{ uri: item.videoUrl }}
            repeat
            onLoad={() => {
                console.log('Video: ', index, '| Loading');
            }}
            onReadyForDisplay={() => {
                console.log('Video: ', index, '| Done');
            }}
            onError={(err) => {
                console.warn('err', err);
            }}
        />
    );
};

const MemoizedVideo = React.memo(Video);

export default MemoizedVideo;
```

I've tried to use Memo to make the flatList more efficient but it doesn't seem to help.
I should mention that not using memo doesn't solve the issue

Here is the Flatlist

```js
const onViewableItemsChanged = useCallback(({ viewableItems }) => {
    if (viewableItems.length > 0) {
        setActiveIndex(viewableItems[0].index);
    }
}, []);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={videos}
                pagingEnabled={true}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                removeClippedSubviews={true}
                initialNumToRender={3}
                maxToRenderPerBatch={3}
                windowSize={5}
                viewabilityConfig={{ viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 100 }}
                onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                        <Post
                            item={item}
                            index={index}
                            paused={index !== activeIndex || tabIndex !== 0}
                            isActive={index >= activeIndex + 1 && index <= activeIndex - 1}
                        />
                    );
                }}
            />
    </View>
);
```

the logs look something like that (for one scroll from [1] to [2])

```
 LOG  Video:  4 | Loading
 LOG  Video:  4 | Done
 LOG  Video:  0 | Loading
 LOG  Video:  0 | Done
 LOG  Video:  2 | Loading
 LOG  Video:  4 | Loading
 LOG  Video:  3 | Loading
 LOG  Video:  2 | Done
 LOG  Video:  1 | Loading
 LOG  Video:  1 | Done
 LOG  Video:  4 | Done
 LOG  Video:  3 | Done
```

Why would they all reload?

Additional infos: when I scroll the next video starts playing before reloading.

Comment: Did you found a solution for the problem?